# Problem of updating the component at a certain event related to time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a web app in React.js using Firestore

I am facing the problem of updating the component
at a certain event related to time.

**~~~~~ Context ~~~~~**

I receive data from custom hook:

```
export default function useFirestoreQuery(query: any) {
  // prettier-ignore
  const [docs, setDocs] = useState<DocumentData | null>([]);

  useEffect(
    () =>
      onSnapshot(query, (snapshot: any) => {
        setDocs(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc: any) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
        );
      }),
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    []
  );

  console.log(query.type + ":");
  console.log(docs);

  return docs;
}
```

in component I get this data, using this hook:

```
  const startOfDay = moment().startOf("day").toDate();
  const endOfDay = moment().endOf("day").toDate();

  const lessonsCollectionRef = collection(firestore, "lessons");
  const lessonsQuery = query(
    lessonsCollectionRef,
    where("beginningTime", ">", startOfDay),
    where("beginningTime", "<=", endOfDay),
    orderBy("beginningTime", "asc")
  );
```

and here is a peace of code, where I show the data:

```
{lessons?.map((lesson: any, index: number) => (
                <Row key={lesson.id}>
                  <Col xs={1}>
                    <Row>
                      <Col xs={12} className="lesson-time">
                        <span className="text-muted">
                          {prettyDateByStamp(lesson.beginningTime.seconds)}
                        </span>
                      </Col>
                      <Col xs={12} className="lesson-time">
                        <span className="text-muted lesson-time">
                          {prettyDateByStamp(lesson.endTime.seconds)}
                        </span>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs={11}>
                    // ~~~~~ Part where I have a problem with ~~~~~
                    <Button
                      disabled={moment(lesson.endTime.seconds * 1000).isBefore(
                        moment()
                      )}
                      variant="secondary"
                      href={lesson.conferenceLink}
                      className="lesson-btn"
                    >
                      <Row>
                        <Col xs={{ span: 1 }} className="lesson-number">
                          <h4>{index + 1}.</h4>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={10} className="lesson-name">
                          <h4>{lesson.name}</h4>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </Button>
                    // ~~~~~ Till here ~~~~~
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              ))}
```

It looks somethins like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRqH6.png

**~~~~~ Problem ~~~~~**

this button has a **disabled** parameter

if **endTime** of the **lesson** isBefore the current time(using moment.js)
the button is **disabled**

it works!..
when the **lesson**'s **endTime** is passed it becomes disabled, but only if I reload the page it updates and becomes disabled

**~~~~~ What I want to have in result ~~~~~**

when the **lesson**'s **endTime** is passed the button related to **lesson**'s document becomes **disabled** without even reloading the page
so the component needs to understand by it self that it needs to re-render

Answer (score 0):

So, in general, I figured out how to fix my problem.

```js
const [time, setTime] = useState(Date.now());

useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => setTime(Date.now()), 10000);
  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  };
}, []);
```

I am just updating React component every 10 seconds. This seems to be working but not optimal solution.